# A question regarding Jacobi fields and families of geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, vector-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to show that for any one-parameter family of geodesics $\gamma(s,t)$ (where $\gamma(s_0,t)$ is a geodesic for any constant $s_0 \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$) defined on a Riemannian manifold $M$, $J=\cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial s}$ is a Jacobi field; that is, $\cfrac{D^2}{dt^2}J(t) + R\left(J(t), \frac{\partial \gamma(0,t)}{\partial t}\right)\frac{\partial \gamma(0,t)}{\partial t}=0$, where $D$ denotes the covariant derivative associated with the metric on $M$.

The book I have been reading offers a proof as follows,
\begin{equation}
\cfrac{D^2}{dt^2}J(t) = \cfrac{D}{dt} \cfrac{D}{dt} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial s}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}=\cfrac{D}{dt} \cfrac{D}{ds} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t},
\end{equation}
by the symmetry of the connection defined on $M$.
\begin{equation}
=\cfrac{D}{ds} \cfrac{D}{dt} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t} + R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t},J(t)\right)\frac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=R\left( \frac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t},J(t)\right)\frac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t},
\end{equation}
as $\gamma(s,t)$ is a geodesic.

I find the second equality to be suspect. Symmetry of the connection would imply that $\cfrac{D}{dt} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial s}-\cfrac{D}{ds} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t}=\left[\cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t},\cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial s}\right]$, and I see no reason why the Lie bracket term would be zero. The Lie bracket of coordinate vector fields is zero, I know, but we don't really know anything about the coordinate system of $M$. If we are using a Riemannian normal coordinate system, then $\cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t}$ is a coordinate vector field, but not $\cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial s}$. Am I missing something? Or are additional conditions required to make the Lie bracket zero?

Comment: This bracket is always zero -- morally, those things sort of *are* coordinate fields, in the sense that they're the pushfowards of $\partial_s$ and $\partial_t$ under the local embedding $\gamma : U \to M$ (where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$).  A precise proof that they're zero should be elementary -- but may depend on how much you know about Lie brackets and what your precise definition of this bracket is. (What *is* your definition?)

Comment: Good points. I have a few questions, though: first, you use the word embedding to describe $\gamma:U \to M$, but there are clearly ways to define $\gamma(s,t)$ such that no embedding is possible. We could, for example, make $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ and have $\gamma$ take $(s,t)$ to $(s+t,0)$. If $\gamma$ DOES define a local embedding, though, it's unclear (to me) how the Lie bracket should be defined, since it acts on vector fields on $M$, when neither $\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial s}$ nor $\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}$ is defined on any open neighborhood in $M$ (if $dim(M) > 2$).

Comment: If $\gamma$ is defined "nicely," (that is, at each $(s,t)$ we can locally embed it into $M$), then it stands to reason that we can extend it to $\gamma^*$ defined an open neighborhood about $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (does this follow from the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem?). This theorem should also give a parametrization of this open neighborhood (in $\mathbb(R)^n$) as well as reparametrization of this neighborhood's image in $M$, wherein $\partial_s$ and $\partial_t$ are coordinate vector fields. Does this work?

Comment: You're definitely right: $\gamma$ is not, in general, an embedding, and in that case it's hard to make sense of this bracket. Your argument is in fact a proof when $\gamma$ is a local embedding for sure. (I don't know that it follows from the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem -- it should be a theorem that any embedding $N$ \to $M$ can be written in suitable coordinates as $x \mapsto (x, 0)$.) However, $D_t \partial_s \gamma = D_s \partial_t \gamma$ is true regardless of whether $\gamma$ is an embedding. Easiest proofs seem to use coordinates: See do Carmo, Chap. 3 Lemma 3.4, or Lee, Lemma 6.3.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! The do Carmo book is a lot better than the resource I was using.

Answer (score 5):

For a general one-parameter family of geodesics, the Lie bracket expression you wrote down has no meaning. The way to prove this, instead, is to choose smooth local coordinates $(x^i)$ on $M$, and write $\gamma$ locally as $\gamma(s,t) = (x^1(s,t),\dots,x^n(s,t))$. Then when you expand out 
$$
\cfrac{D}{dt} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial s}-\cfrac{D}{ds} \cfrac{\partial \gamma(s,t)}{\partial t}
$$
in coordinates, you get an expression involving
$$
\frac{\partial^2 x^k(s,t)}{\partial t\,\partial s}
-
\frac{\partial^2 x^k(s,t)}{\partial s\,\partial t},
$$ 
which is clearly zero.

This is carried out in detail in my book *Riemannian Manifolds*, Lemma 6.8.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry of the connection means that $$\frac{D}{dt} \cdot \frac{\partial γ(s,t)}{\partial s}= \frac{D}{ds}\cdot \frac{\partialγ(s,t)}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).